# Find a number which satisfies the equation $|x^6-3x^3+5x| \leq Q$ whenever $|x|$ $\leq$ $2$?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

NOTE (EDIT): I have noticed that no one noticed that a TRIANGLE INEQUALITY is being used. Hence, part of the confusion in my comments of the solution.

TRIANGLE INEQUALITY:

$|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$, important part to note that there is $\leq$ symbol.

So there this question in which a number has to be found such that it satisfys the following equation (whenever $|x|$ $\leq$ $2$):

Also: this is strictly a proofs question and no calculus is allowed. Thanks.

$|x^6-3x^3+5x| \leq Q$ whenever $|x|$ $\leq$ $2$

$(1)$ $\leq |x^6+(-3x^3)+5x|$

$(2)$ $\leq |x^6|+|-3x^3|+|5x|$

$(3)$ $\leq |x|^6+3*|x|^3+5*|x|$

$(4)$ $\leq 2^6 + 3*2^3 + 5*2 = 98$

The question is: what is the problem asking for? Does it say to find a number in which it satisfies an expression between the interval of $x$ in $[-2, 2]$? Why do you substitute $|x|$ with $2$ specifically and not any other numbers? And, apparently, this solution can be done in another way to end up with another answer... because any number higher than 98 is also the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we have that for $|x|\le 2$

$$0-24-10\le x^6-3x^3+5x\le  64+24+10 \implies |x^6-3x^3+5x|\le 98$$

Note that the problem is not asking for the "minimum value $Q$ such that..." but simply for any value $Q$ which satisfy the inequality. Therefore the solution $Q=98$, even if it is not the minimal possible answer, is correct as any other $Q\ge 98$.

Comment: BTW, $98$ is *not* the minimal possible answer

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes of course! I specify that better.

Comment: @gimusi Hi, I am not sure how you got the numbers such as $0 - 12 - 10$ in your answer? Also may you answer the other questions asked in the post if you can? Thanks.

Comment: @Strikers I've used that $x^6\ge 0$ $-3x^3\ge -24$ and $5x \ge -10$. I've just now realized that I let $-3x^2\ge -12$ according to the original version. I fix that.

Comment: @Strikers Which is exactly the other question you are referring to?

Comment: Hi. If you could explicitly state how you get $-3x^3\ge -24$ and why you would do that? Thanks.

Comment: @gimusi Under my problem, I asked some questions in the post.

Comment: @Strikers Since $x^3$ is a strictly increasing function we have that $-3x^3$ is strictly decreasing and the minimum value is attained at the maximum value for $x$ that is $x=2$.

Comment: @Strikers Yes I've read but it seems to me that I've answered to all the points. Which one exactly is not clear to you?

Comment: @gimusi Hi so I am asking why we substitute $|x| = 2$ and not any other number? Also I am still unsure how you get the expression is less than $0-24-10$ i.e. where did the numbers come from? Thanks.

Comment: @Strikers We want estimate the bounds for $x^6-3x^3+5x$ when $x\in[-2,2]$. Then we can consider separetely $x^6$, $-3x^3$ and $5x$ to obtain $0\le x^6\le 64$, $-24\le -3x^3\le 24$ and $-10\le 5x\le 10$ and therefore $$0-24-10\le x^6-3x^3+5x \le 64+24+10$$ that is $|x^6-3x^3+5x|\le 98$. It is  just a simple way to obtain a bound that works (even if not optimal).

Comment: @Strikers Note that we use the values $x=-2$ and $x=2$ for the estimations because all the three functions $x^6$, $-3x^3$ and $5x$ are monotonic and each one reaches  its extrema values for the extrema values of $x$.

Comment: Hi. Why do you consider anything separately? Why don't you remove the absolute values like I did in the solution? Why are you considering $0 \leq x^6 \leq 64$ and same goes for $-3x^3$? Sorry, but if you are still answering I'd like to ask these questions. Thanks.

Comment: @Strikers What are the maximum and minimum values for $x^6$ for $|x|\le 2$ that is $-2\le x \le 2$?

Comment: @Gimusi Okay, I get that, thanks. So why are there so many ways of doing this problem and is mine valid enough? How would I know that for mine I have obtained the minimum value?

Comment: @Gimusi 64. Yes, okay.

Comment: @Strikers and the minimum? And what the minimum and maximum for the other 2 terms?

Comment: @Strikers Your way is correct for the given problem. You indeed have used that $|A+B+C| \le |A|+|B|+|C|\le \max|A|+\max|B|+\max|C|$. Yes there are other ways to solve the problem but it is usual in math. We know that 98 is not the best estimation since we are adding $\max(|-3x^3|)$ and $ \max(|5x|)$ but the first one occurs at $x=-2$ and the second one at $x=2$.

Comment: @gimusi Okay, thank you.

Comment: @Strikers You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @Strikers Of course $x^6\ge 0$ is monotonic increasing for $x\in [0,2]$.

Comment: @gimusi Hi I was just wondering, in my question after I manipulated the original equation to get $x$, why did I not end up with $98$? Why is it that the maximum value of my final expression gives the answer to the original?

Comment: @Strikers How is your derivation?

Comment: @gimusi Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Strikers You are claiming "...in my question after I manipulated the original equation to get x, why did I not end up with 98?..." but it seems that you end up with that.

Comment: @gimusi Sorry I meant why did I end up with $98$? Why not the maximum of the original equation, which is $78$?

Comment: @Strikers As noticed we are estimating an upper bound summing up the maximum for each term, but each masimum is attained for different values of x and therefore 98 is not th eoptimal value but, as altready noticed, is perfectly fine to solve the given problem.

Comment: @gimusi But isn't there a possibility that the maximum of the derived equation is not going to satisfy the original equation?

Comment: No because it is greater than the optimal value, we are summing up the maximum and therefore it is a safe extimation.

Comment: @gimusi Where does it say that it is greater than the optimal value? And what do you mean by "we are summing up the maximum"? Thank you for your time and explanation expertise.

Comment: @gimusi I noticed that a triangle inequality is being used, I think that solves most of my confusion. You can edit your solution for a better answer if you want. Thanks.

Comment: @Strikers Well done! That’s of course a good reference to keep in mind! Bye

Answer (score 2):

For $-2\le x\le 2$, we have $0\le x^2\le 4$, hence  $-5\le 3x^2-5 \le 7$, and
$$\tag1|x^6-3x^3+5x|\le |x|^6+|3x^3-5|\cdot|x|\le 64+7\cdot 2=78. $$
Hence you can pick $Q=78$ or any value $\ge 78$ (in particular, $Q=98$ is valid and apparently easier shown to be good). Note that $x=-2$ leads to $x^6-3x^3+5x=78$, hence the bound $(1)$ cannot be improved.

Comment: Hi. I am confused to how you got $-5\le 3x^2-5 \le 7$ and why you decided to separate the equation into $|x|^6+|3x^3-5|\cdot|x|$. Also how would you know that 78 is the lowest possible answer? Thanks.